# error al agregar items al carrito de compras

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

estoy con un problema, que cuando quiero agregar items a mi carrito, solo me permite agregar 2 items y en mongoDB(estoy usando Atlas) me aparece la coleccion con 1 solo item agregado en el carrito, cualquier idea de como resolverlo es bienvenida.

aqui mi modelo

```
const { Schema, Types, model } = require("mongoose");

const cartSchema = new Schema({
  customer: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  
  items: [
    {
      product: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "product",
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});

const Cart = model("cart", cartSchema);
module.exports = Cart;
```

aqui el codigo del Controller

```
    addToCart: async (req, res) => {
    const { product, quantity } = req.body; 
    const cart = await cartModel.findOne({customer: req.user.sub})
    if(cart){
      const found = cart.items.find((product) =>{
        return product._id === product 
      })
      if(found){
        const cart = cartModel.update( 
          { customer: req.user.sub },
          { $inc: { items : { quantity : quantity } } },
          { safe: true });
        return res.json(cart);
      }
      cart.items.push({product, quantity})
      return res.json(cart)
    }
    const newCart = new cartModel({
      customer: req.user.sub,
      items:[{product, quantity}]
    });
    const result = await newCart.save();
    return res.json(result);   
  },
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, dices que sólo te permite agregar 2 ítems, pero el controlador recibe uno solo: `const { product, quantity } = req.body;`. Por otra parte esto: `const found = cart.items.find((product) => { ... });` lo veo innecesario. ¿Podrías aclarar exactamente qué envías a tu ruta y porqué dices que sólo te permite 2 items? Si te permite sólo 2 items (por diseño), ¿cómo los envías a tu backend?. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar un documento en una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com) que representa un *carrito* de compras, modificando la cantidad de productos dentro de una lista de productos. Sin embargo al intentar realizar la actualización, la misma no ocurre o simplemente actualiza 1 único elemento de la lista.

El problema es el comando usado para la actualización del elemento de la lista.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución al problema puede ser la siguiente, sin embargo, dependiendo de la lógica de tu aplicación, tal vez necesites ajustarla un poco a tus necesidades.

Tu esquema de datos incluye una lista de elementos llamada `items`, la cual contiene documentos con la siguiente estructura:

```js
{
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "product",
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  }
}
```

Al actualizar un documento de la colección `carts` (asumiré que ese el nombre de la colección donde se almacenan los documentos) tenemos 3 escenarios de actualización:

1. Se añade 1 nuevo producto a la lista de `items`.
2. Se modifica un elemento existente en la lista de `items`.
3. Se elimina un elemento existente en la lista de `items`.

En el caso planteado en la pregunta, se desea añadir elementos nuevos a la lista de `items`. Por eso me enfocaré sólo en el primer caso.

**Añadir un (o varios) elemento(s) a la lista**

Para añadir un elemento nuevo a la lista `items` podemos usar el operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) y el operador de filtro [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/index.html) de MongoDB, con el método [`findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), por ejemplo:

```js
const element = { product: req.body.product, quantity: req.body.quantity };
Cart.findOneAndUpdate({customer: req.user.sub, 'items.product': {$nin: [element.product]}}, { $push: {items: element}, {new: true}, callback);
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que el método `findAndUpdateOne` buscará el documento de la colección `carts`, cuyo campo `customer` se corresponda con el valor de `req.user.sub` y que no contenga ningún elemento identificado por el campo `product` equivalente al producto que deseamos añadir (por ello el uso de `$nin`).

¿Porqué?

Esto es una forma de evitar añadir 2 elementos del mismo tipo, es decir evitamos añadir un elemento que ya exista en la lista. Luego, si la actualización del *carrito* no se realiza porque el elemento ya está repetido, podemos enviar un mensaje al usuario indicando el problema, para que intente la operación nuevamente usando bien otro producto o actualizando la cantidad del existente. Sin embargo, usualmente esta validación se realiza desde el lado cliente. Pero es bueno y necesario validar desde el lado servidor como en este caso.

Ahora, notemos algo importante: no hago una validación para saber si el producto existe en nuestra base de datos en la colección de productos, esto lo puedo delegar a un *middleware* de validación de los datos recibidos.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const validarExistencia = (req, res, next) => {
  Product.findById(req.body.product, (error, product) => {
    if(error) {
      // manejo de error usualmente llamando a next(error)
      return next(error);
    }
    if(!product) {
      // si no existe el producto, enviar mensaje al cliente:
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: true,
        message: 'El producto solicitado no existe en los registros'
      });
    }
    // si llegamos aquí, el producto existe y podemos continuar
    next();
  });
}
```

En tu ruta, lo único que debes hacer es encadenar los *middleware* de tal forma que se ejecute primero la validación y luego la inserción del nuevo elemento:

```js
// ejemplo de ruta en Express
router.route('/cart')
.get(showCart)
.post(validarExistencia, addToCart); // <- primero se ejecuta la validación y sólo se ejecuta el siguiente middleware si la validación es positiva.
```

**Mejora**

¿Qué sucede si un cliente desea agregar varios productos a la lista en una misma solicitud?

Lo ideal es tener un solo método que se encargue de insertar elementos nuevos en la lista sin importar la cantidad de los mismos, sea uno o varios.

Esto implica un cambio en la forma en que trabajamos con el envío de los datos desde el cliente.

Supongamos que el cliente envía una lista en `req.body.items`, entonces podemos insertar cada elemento de la lista usando el modificador [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) en nuestro operador `$push`. También implica realizar un cambio en la función *middleware* de validación.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
// añadimos elementos de una lista
const elements = req.body.itemsToInsert; // <- es una lista con elementos a insertar
const products = elements.map(element => { // <- valores para verificar que no se repiten en los elementos que ya hay en la lista de items del documento
  return element.product;
});
Cart.findOneAndUpdate({customer: req.user.sub, 'items.product': {$nin: products}}, { $push: {items: {$each: elements}}, {new: true} callback);
```

Con esto estamos realizando en una sola operación la inserción de selección múltiple en caso de que la aplicación lo permita. Por ejemplo, el cliente puede elegir añadir a la vez más de 1 producto en una sola consulta. Además se sigue verificando que no exista ningún elemento repetido.

Sin embargo, esto va a requerir que nuestra función `callback` determine cuál es el elemento repetido y solicite al usuario volver a realizar la operación eliminando el documento repetido o usando alguna combinación de actualización de la cantidad del producto repetido e inserción de los nuevos. La lógica para esto dependerá del alcance de tu aplicación.

Nuestro *middleware* de validación se encargará de filtrar los productos que realmente existan en nuestra DB y los incorporará en una lista llamada `itemsToInsert` en el objeto `req`, ya que nuestra función de inserción lee los datos en ese campo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const validarExistencia = (req, res, next) => {
  let productIds = req.body.items.map(item => { 
    return item.product;
  }
  Product.find({ _id: {$in: productIds} }, (error, products) => { // find devuelve una lista
    if(error) {
      // manejo de error usualmente llamando a next(error)
      return next(error);
    }
    if(!products.length) {
      // si ningún producto existe, enviar mensaje al cliente:
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: true,
        message: 'Los productos solicitados no existen en los registros'
      });
    }
    // almacenamos los items que sí existen y continuamos
    req.itemsToInsert = req.body.items.filter(item => {
      for(let product of products) {
        if(product._id.toString() === item.product) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false; // <- si llegamos aquí es que no hay productos coincidentes
    });
    next();
  });
}
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es verificar la existencia de cada producto recibido en la lista. Como los valores recibidos en el campo `product` de cada elemento de `req.body.items` es de tipo `String`, la comparación contra el campo `_id` de cada producto encontrado en la Base de Datos debo hacerla convirtiendo este campo `_id` a su representación de cadena, para ello utilizo el método [`toString()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#ObjectId.toString) del tipo [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) de MongoDB.

De esta forma estarás actualizando la lista de productos al añadir cualquier cantidad de elementos enviados por el cliente.

Hasta aquí espero que tu pregunta o duda sea resuelta.

Los otros 2 casos, que no son menos importantes, serían una pregunta diferente, y te invito a plantear la pregunta en el sitio para poder ayudarte con mucho gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un `exec` para que se ejecute el `update`.

```
    addToCart: async (req, res) => {
    const { product, quantity } = req.body; 
    const cart = await cartModel.findOne({customer: req.user.sub})
    if(cart){
      const found = cart.items.find((product) =>{
        return product._id === product 
      })
      if(found){
        //Aquí tambien es necesario await
        const cart = await cartModel.update( 
          { customer: req.user.sub },
          
           //EDICION----------------------
          //Agrega tus campos con notacion de punto asi:
          { $inc: { "items.quantity": quantity } } },
          { safe: true })
           //Esto es necesario para guarde la modificacion. 
           .exec()
        //Obtienes de nuevo el objeto modificado. 
        cart = await cartModel.findOne({customer: req.user.sub})
        return res.json(cart);
      }
      cart.items.push({product, quantity})
      return res.json(cart)
    } 

    const newCart = new cartModel({
      customer: req.user.sub,
      items:[{product, quantity}]
    });
    const result = await newCart.save();
    return res.json(result);   
    
    
  },
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya probe el codigo agregando el await y el exec, pero sigue igual, solo me agrega 2 items en postman, cuando quiero agregar un tercer item, me modifica el ultimo agregado, y en mongoDb Atlas, solo me muestra el array con 1 item

Comment: Edite la respuesta. Dime si te funciona.